# Ruby on Rails sort array of multiple active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting, activerecord

I have 2 type of active record (objects):

**1. Project**

```
<Project:0x007fd1b3ef3c10
id: 1,
min_price: 1000,
max_price: 2000>
```

**2. Property**

```
<Property:0x007fd1b3ef3c15
id: 1,
price: 1000>
```

and they are on an array [project, property, project, etc..]
I need to sort them by `price`, but if it's project type then I should use `min_price`. Can I do that in rails?
I've tried to use `sort_by` but doesn't work.

Example

```
[
  <project  id:1, min_price:1, max:price:100>,
  <property id:2,     price:5>,
  <project  id:3, min_price:3, max:price:100>,
]
```

I want it to return :

```
[
  <project  id:1, min_price:1, max:price:100>,
  <project  id:3, min_price:3, max:price:100>,
  <property id:2,     price:5>,

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several choices: define a common method for both these models or just use `sort_by` with a block that dynamically decides what method to use for sorting. Check out this snippet:

```
class Project
  attr_accessor :min_price

  alias_method :sort_price, :min_price

  def initialize(min_price)
    @min_price = min_price
  end
end

class Property
  attr_accessor :price

  alias_method :sort_price, :price

  def initialize(price)
    @price = price
  end
end

collection = [Project.new(10), Property.new(20), Project.new(5), Property.new(7)]
puts collection.sort_by(&:sort_price).inspect

puts(collection.sort_by do |record|
  record.is_a?(Project) ? record.min_price : record.price
end.inspect)
```

I personally prefer the solution with a common method because it's more object oriented (follows polymorphism). If you don't like to pollute your models you can make a decorator for sorting:

```
class SortingItem
  attr_reader :object

  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def sort_price
    case @object
    when Project
      @object.min_price
    when Property
      @object.price
    else
      fail ArgumentError, "unknown sorting item - #{object.class}"
    end
  end
end

class Project
  attr_accessor :min_price

  def initialize(min_price)
    @min_price = min_price
  end
end

class Property
  attr_accessor :price

  def initialize(price)
    @price = price
  end
end

def decorate(object)
  SortingItem.new(object)
end

collection = [decorate(Project.new(10)), decorate(Property.new(20)), decorate(Project.new(5)), decorate(Property.new(7))]
puts collection.sort_by(&:sort_price).map(&:object).inspect
```